# How can i get matrix column ouput from certain column

Tags: r, matrix, output

```
matriisi <- matrix(c(1.3,1.4,1.2,1.9,1.9,2.9,3.0,4.2,5.1,5.5), nrow= 5, byrow = FALSE, )
colnames (matriisi) <- c("y","x")
matriisi
datat <- data.frame(matriisi)
havainnot <- datat[which(datat$x>3.0),]
havainnot
```

I got following results:

```
    y   x
3 1.2 4.2
4 1.9 5.1
5 1.9 5.5
```

How can i get only the values from the second column, which in this case is X? Why does it show both columns?

Comment: `datat$x[datat$x>3.0]`

Comment: Although which is not required, if you want to use it: > datat$x[which(datat$x>3.0)]
[1] 4.2 5.1 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values of the second column if you reference by name:

```
matriisi[, "x"]
2.9 3.0 4.2 5.1 5.5

havainnot[, "x"]
4.2 5.1 5.5`
```

If you want by row, you can use

```
matriisi[1,]
  y   x 
1.3 2.9 

havainnot[1,]
    y   x
3 1.2 4.2
```

Or you can selectt given a row and column.

```
havainnot[1,"x"]
4.2

havainnot[2,"x"]
5.1
```

Then, once you know the data you want, you can create a matrix using next syntax:

```
havainnot <- matrix(havainnot[2,"x"])
```